# Django weird method not allowed

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, django-views, django-urls

I am coding a project using Django when requesting a url I get a weird Not Allowed Mthod(405).
I what is the error about but here is my implementations and details:

urls.py

```
url(r'^join/',
        csrf_protect(UserSignUp.as_view()),
        name='sgn_up'),
```

views.py

```
class UserSignUp(View):

    def post(self, request):
        resp_data = {}
        try:
            print 'sign up================================================'
            x = MyUser.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])
            resp_data['message'] = 'signed up before'
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(resp_data), content_type="application/json")

        except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            user = MyUser(email=request.POST['email'],
                          password=request.POST['password'],
                          first_name=request.POST['firstName'],
                          last_name=request.POST['lastName']
                          )
            user.save()
            #print 'errorize'
            user.set_password(request.POST['password'])
            user.save()
            resp_data[
                'message'] = 'please refer to your email for complete registrations'
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(resp_data), content_type="application/json")
```

HTML/JS

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    var csrftoken = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').prop('value');
    function sameOrigin(url) {
        var host = document.location.host; // host + port
        var protocol = document.location.protocol;
        var sr_origin = '//' + host;
        var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
        // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
        return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
            (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
            // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
            !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
    function ajaxSignIn(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"{% url 'sgn_in' %}",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#sgn-in-form').serialize(),
            dataType : "json",
            success: function(json){location.reload();},
            error: function(xhr, status) {}
        });
    }
    function ajaxSignUp(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"{% url 'sgn_up' %}",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#sgn-up-form').serialize(),
            dataType : "json",
            success: function(json){location.reload();},
            error: function(xhr, status) {}
        });
    }
```

Now I send an ajax request (I have included csrftoken) and post method but I get a 405!
I have other ajax post request with csrftokens bur they working as well(e.g. sign-in)!

The most funny thing about this is that when I use Chrome it gives the error and user data also is saved in the DB!!!(this means that the model post method worked!!!) But when using firefox it only gives error!
Does anyone had encountered such problems? I searched alot but found nothing that helps!
Thanks

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are sending a POST request?

Comment: Yes, Absolutely. I have updated my question to see html/js.
for more emphasis: My ajaxSignIn works well but sign up hangs up and more stupid: see different functionalities from request from different browsers!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your def post you will also have to include the context.

```
    self.object = self.get_object()
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return self.render_to_response(context)`
```